# SQL Query to select one set when there are duplicates

Tags: sql

[image]

```
SELECT REF_ID, MIN(SLA) FROM [SLA] WHERE [FIRST_DATE] > '2016-09-30' GROUP BY  [REF_ID]
```

This will list the items with minimum SLA when there are duplicates

```
REF_ID    |    COUNT  
11    |    1  
12    |    1  
13    |    1  
14    |    2
```

I would like to get the count of SLAs, Can someone provide a query for this please.

```
SLA    |    COUNT  
1    |    3  
2    |    1  
0    |    0
```

Thanks

Comment: you can't do `select count(*),sla ... group by sla`?

Comment: Where does `SLA` "0" come from?  It is not in the data.

Comment: Sorry, Please ignore the 0

Answer (score 1):

To get the number of SLAs:

```
select SLA, count(SLA) from table group by SLA
```

Comment: I think it will count the duplicate as well. When there are duplicates, I want to count the SLA 1 only. (It will list 3 and 3 but result should be 3 and 1. Thanks

Comment: APP_ID 101 and 102 have duplicates and I want to count only the  SLA 1 for both and ignore SLA 2

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT MINSLA, COUNT(MINSLA)
FROM (SELECT REF_ID, MIN(SLA) AS MINSLA
      FROM [SLA]
      WHERE [FIRST_DATE] > '2016-09-30'
      GROUP BY [REF_ID]
     ) r
GROUP BY MINSLA
```

Comment: I am upvoting even though this doesn't return *exactly* what the OP wants.  It is missing the `0` value.