# SQL Query to select one set when there are multiple entries

Tags: sql-server

I asked this question ([SQL Query to select one set when there are duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40290178/sql-query-to-select-one-set-when-there-are-duplicates)) last year and got the solution to count the SLAs. Basically, count the number of minimum SLA for each application.  However, I have a follow-up question. I want a query that will return the rows of the minimum SLA and earliest date for each REF_ID (or APP_ID)

```
 
ID |  REF_ID  | APP_ID  | FIRST_DATE | SECOND_DTE  |  SLA  |  
1  | 11       | 101     | 2016/10/01 | 2016/10/02  |  1    |
2  | 12       | 102     | 2016/10/01 | 2016/10/04  |  2    |
3  | 12       | 102     | 2016/10/01 | 2016/10/05  |  2    |
```

So the query should return the first and second row.
I would very much appreciate if someone could provide a solution.

I have updated the query based on User726720 answer. This does not return entire rows but sufficient data.

SELECT REF_ID, MIN(SECOND_DTE), MIN(SLA) FROM TABLE WHERE FIRST_DTE > '2016-10-01' AND FIRST_DTE < '2016-11-01' GROUP BY REF_ID

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job:

```
    Select * from table 
    WHERE SLA =  ( SELECT MIN(SLA) FROM table) 
    and SECOND_DTE = ( SELECT MIN(SECOND_DTE ) FROM table)
```

Comment: Thank you user726720. However, I am seeing duplicates. I will check it later. (Each app_id/Ref_id should have only one entry).